# Is there a Special Dialog Grunt "Easter egg" in Halo 4?

Tags: halo-4

Previous installments in the series (though not all) featured a special Easter egg encounter with a [Special Dialog Grunt](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Dialogue_Grunt).  Does Halo 4 feature such an encounter?  If so, what are the requirements I must complete in order to see it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If there is a Legendary ending then the requirements, almost by definition, are "complete the game on Legendary"

Comment: @murgatroid99 After some research, I found the Easter eggs I was remembering were actually not "endings", the were just encounters with what has been termed "Special Dialog Grunts".  It so happened that the Grunt in Halo 3 was very near the end, on Legendary - and I accidentally munged the two.  Hopefully my question will make more sense now.

Comment: @EBongo But there actually *was* an Easter Egg ending in the first Halo upon completing the game on Legendary.

Comment: Finding all those secrets sure builds up a Big Grunty Thirst!

Comment: @Fluttershy Yes, there was.  However as murgatroid99 points out, I don't believe there was any requirement, beyond simply completing the game on Legendary.  In fact I believe there have been Legendary endings for all or most of the games in the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no Special Dialog Grunt in Halo 4. Halo 1, 2, and 3 all had special dialog grunts, but no game since then has. This may likely be an easter egg that was left behind when the original trilogy ended. But, there are [other easter eggs in Halo 4](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Halo_4_Easter_Eggs) to find.